# How to handle trigger notification of Postgres table using data jpa?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, triggers

How to handle trigger notification of Postgres table using data jpa, need to monitor db table trigger

I tried with jdbc- driver but required solution is using data- jpa.

Is it possible to track db trigger using data-jpa?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `@EventListener` annotation along with Spring Data JPA's `@RepositoryEventHandler` feature.

**Create Entity Class:**
Define an entity class representing the PostgreSQL table you want to monitor for changes.

**Create Repository Interface:**
Create a repository interface for your entity class by extending `JpaRepository` or another appropriate Spring Data JPA repository interface.

**Create Event Listener:**
Create an event listener class to handle trigger notifications from the PostgreSQL table.

```java
@Component
public class EntityEventListener {

    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;

    @EventListener
    public void handlePostgresNotification(Event payloadEvent) {
        repository.findAll(); // Reload data from the database
    }
}
```

**Enable Asynchronous Execution (Optional):**
If you expect a high volume of trigger notifications or if handling notifications might be time-consuming, consider enabling asynchronous execution for the event listener method.

```java
@Async
@EventListener
public void handlePostgresNotification(Event payloadEvent) {
    // Handle PostgreSQL trigger notification asynchronously
}
```

**Configure PostgreSQL Trigger:**
Set up a trigger on the PostgreSQL table to send notifications whenever data changes. You can use PostgreSQL's `NOTIFY` command within your trigger function to send a notification to a specific channel.

**Handle Notification in Spring Boot:**
When the PostgreSQL trigger sends a notification, your Spring Boot application will receive it, and the event listener method annotated with `@EventListener` will be invoked automatically. You can then handle the notification as needed, such as reloading data from the database.

This approach allows you to react to database changes in real time and take appropriate actions within your application.

Comment: how to update jsonb column in postgress using data-jpa?

Comment: Use the repository interface to update the JSONB column in your database and invoke the update method from your service layer with the ID of the entity you want to update and the new JSON data.

Ex: 

YourEntity entity = repository.findById(id).orElse(null);
 if (entity != null) { entity.setJsonData(newData); repository.save(entity); }
      
Trigger the method:
   // Example usage: Update JSON data for the entity with ID 1
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   JsonNode newData = mapper.readTree("{\"key\": \"value\"}");
   service.updateJsonData(1L, newData);

Comment: How to create entity for jsonb?

Comment: Use a custom data type (Map<String, Object> or a custom POJO) to represent the JSON data.

private Map<String, Object> jsonData  or 
private JsonDataObj jsonData